# Target element by width attribute

Tags: css

Is it possible to target a `td` element without ID, but with a specific CSS attribute value, like this:

```
<td width="50%"></td>
```

I have this in the HTML, and I just do not need it.
Thank you

Comment: If you don't need it, then why don't you remove it?

Comment: You should also avoid using inline css unless you need it to load instantly, it's in an email, or it's generated at runtime, to improve maintainability and readability.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors

```css
td[width='50%'] {
  width: 600px;
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td width="50%">TD</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Note: The `<TD>`'s `width` **attribute** is **obsolete** in HTML5 (might still work). Preferably use CSS `style`
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/td

Comment: Are you *sure* this works? Will style override the attribute?

Comment: @Amit yes it will.

Comment: @Amit it's not obsolete, it's deprecated and still working in all browsers for backward compatibility. The *of course this works* is simply related to the use of Attribute selectors. And yes here's a demo: http://jsbin.com/xonuwun/1/edit?html,css,output

Comment: Actually, the HTML5 spec uses the term [obsolete](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/obsolete.html#obsolete), not deprecated throughout, but that's pretty irrelevant. As you rightly point out, what matters is that it's still *implemented*.

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML didn't show up in your question, because you forgot to use code blocks.

Regardless, it sounds like you're asking about CSS Attribute selectors.  These allow you to select HTML elements based on their attribute values.  For example:

```
<style type="text/css">
  td[width="50%"] {
     color:red;
  }
</style>
```

[More info](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_attribute_selectors.asp) found at W3Schools.com

Answer (score -1):

```css
td{
  background:red;
  width:50%;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <td>Test</td>
</table>
```